# Webscrape using BeautifulSoup to Dataframe

Tags: html, python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the html code:

```
    <div class="wp-block-atomic-blocks-ab-accordion ab-block-accordion ab-font-size-18"><details><summary class="ab-accordion-title"><strong>American Samoa</strong></summary><div class="ab-accordion-text">
    <ul><li><strong><a href="https://www.americansamoa.gov/covid-19-advisories" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" aria-label="American Samoa Department of Health Travel Advisory (opens in a new tab)">American Samoa Department of Health Travel Advisory</a></strong></li><li>March 2, 2020—Governor&nbsp;Moliga&nbsp;<a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="https://www.rnz.co.nz/international/pacific-news/410783/american-samoa-establishes-govt-taskforce-to-plan-for-coronavirus" target="_blank">appointed</a>&nbsp;a government taskforce&nbsp;to provide a plan for preparation and response to the covid-19 coronavirus.&nbsp;</li></ul>
    
    <ul><li>March 25, 2020 – The Governor <a href="https://6fe16cc8-c42f-411f-9950-4abb1763c703.filesusr.com/ugd/4bfff9_2d3c78a841824b8aafe05032f853585b.pdf">issued</a> an Executive Order 001 recognizing the Declared Public Health Emergency and State of Emergency, and imminent threat to public health. The order requires the immediate and comprehensive enforcement by the Commissioner of Public Safety, Director of Health, Attorney General, and other agency leaders.
    <ul>
    <li>Business are also required to provide necessary supplies to the public and are prohibited from price gouging.</li>
    </ul>
    </li></ul>
</div></details></div>
```

I want to extract State, date and text and add to a dataframe with these three columns

State: American Samoa
Date: 2020-03-25
Text: The Governor Executive Order 001 recognizing the Declared Public Health Emergency and State of Emergency, and imminent threat to public health

My code so far:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)
for tag in soup.find_all("summary"):
    print("{0}: {1}".format(tag.name, tag.text))
    for tag1 in soup.find_all("li"):
        #print(type(tag1))
        ln = tag1.text
        dt = (ln.split(' – ')[0])
        dt = (dt.split('—')[0])
        #txt = ln.split(' – ')[1]
        print(dt)
```

Need Help:

1. How to get the text till a "." only, I dont need the entire test
2. How to add to the dataframe as new row as I loop through (I have only attached a part if the source code of webpage)

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you check your html for accuracy? For example, where do`<details>` and `<div class="ab-accordion-text">` close?

Comment: <div class="ab-accordion-text"> does not close anywhere and I have updated the HTML code for <details>

Comment: Good. And if there's more than one item, does it appear under `<details> ` as another `<summary>` etc. or as another set of `<details>`?

Comment: yes, its a huge webpage that I am reading from, another section starts -<div class="wp-block-atomic-blocks-ab-accordion ab-block-accordion ab-font-size-18"><details><summary class="ab-accordion-title"><strong>California</strong></summary><div class="ab-accordion-text">
<p><a rel="noreferrer noopener" aria-label=" (opens in a new tab)" href="https://covid19.ca.gov/" target="_blank"><strong>California coronavirus resource page.</strong></a></p>

Comment: Can you post the URL of the page you want to scrape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start I have added the code below. Unfortunately the web page is not uniform in it's use of HTML lists some `ul` elements contain nested `ul`s others don't. This code is not perfect but a starting point, for example `American Samoa` has an absolute mess of nested `ul` elements so only appears once in the `df`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
}
# You need to specify User Agent headers or else you get a 403
data = requests.get("https://www.nga.org/coronavirus-state-actions-all/", headers=HEADERS).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
rows_list = []
for detail in soup.find_all("details"):
    state = detail.find('summary')
    ul = detail.find('ul')
    for li in ul.find_all('li', recursive=False):
        # Three types of hyphen are used on this webpage
        split = re.split('(?:-|–|—)', li.text, 1)
        if len(split) == 2:
            rows_list.append([state.text, split[0], split[1]])
        else:
            print("Error", li.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.max_colwidth', -1):
    print(df)
```

It creates and prints a data frame with 547 rows and prints some error messages for text it can not split. You will have to work out exactly which data you need and how to tweak the code to suit your purpose.

You can use 'html.parser' if you don't have 'lxml' installed.

**UPDATED**
Another approach is to use regex to match any string beginning with a date:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
}
# You need to specify User Agent headers or else you get a 403
data = requests.get("https://www.nga.org/coronavirus-state-actions-all/", headers=HEADERS).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
rows_list = []
for detail in soup.find_all("details"):
    state = detail.find('summary')
    for li in detail.find_all('li'):
        p = re.compile(r'(\s*(Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\s*(\d{1,2}),*\s*(\d{4}))', re.IGNORECASE)
        m = re.match(p, li.text)
        if m:
            rows_list.append([state.text, m.group(0), m.string.replace(m.group(0), '')])
        else:
            print("Error", li.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

this gives far more records 4,785. Again it is a starting point some data gets missed but far less. It writes the data to a csv file, out.csv.